# [PHP][MySQL] How to insert data in 2 tables at same time?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little problem to insert data in 2 tables and need some help with it.

For example:

**Table 1:**

```
CREATE TABLE tb1 (
    tb1_id int(5) not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    tb1_title varchar(50),
    tb1_cat varchar(50)
);
```

**Table 2:**

```
CREATE TABLE tb2 (
    tb2_id int(5) not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    tb2_title varchar(50),
    tb2_doc varchar(200),
    id_tb1 int(5) not null REFERENCES tb1(tb1_id)
);
```

One entry of `tb1` can have many information(rows) of `tb2`, but how to insert the id of `tb1` in some rows of `tb2`?

**formular.php:**

```
$sqla = "INSERT INTO tb_1 (tb1_title, tb1_cat) VALUES ('$tb1_title', '$tb1_cat')";
$sqlb = "INSERT INTO tb_2 (tb2_title, tb2_doc, <b>[? ? ?]</b>) VALUES ('$tb2_title', '$tb2_doc', <b>[? ? ?]</b>)";

mysqli_query($db, $sqla);
mysqli_query($db, $sqlb);
```

What do I have to change here?

Comment: Use `mysqli_insert_id()` to get tb1 id

Comment: where exactly? I'm new to database designing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of `tb1_id` using [`mysqli_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php), and then insert that into `tb2`:

```
$sqla = "INSERT INTO tb1 (tb1_title, tb1_cat) VALUES ('$tb1_title', '$tb1_cat')";
if (mysqli_query($db, $sqla)) {
    $tb1_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);
    $sqlb = "INSERT INTO tb2 (tb2_title, tb2_doc, id_tb1) VALUES ('$tb2_title', '$tb2_doc', $tb1_id)";
    mysqli_query($db, $sqlb);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? `$tb1_id` is assigned the value of `tb1_id` from the first insert using `mysqli_insert_id`, and then it is used in the second query as the value for `id_tb1` in `tb2` (if you scroll right on the code you will see it at the end of the `$sqlb` assignment).

Comment: using this code, would it still needed to use REFERENCES tb1(tb1_id) or is it a have to?

Comment: It's not necessary but it is a good thing to do. for example if you try to delete an entry in `tb1` that is referenced in `tb2` you will get an error.

Comment: When I insert multiple data at same time, then i get some problems with mysqli_insert_id() ... For example there are already 4 posts in tb1 and 11 docs in tb2 in the database. Now i want upload a post (tb1) with 3 docs (tb2), with the post number 5. The first doc (would be tb2_id #12) gets the correct tb1_id #5, but the second file gets then the tb1_id #12. So it seems mysqli_insert_id() takes always the last id, no matter if tb1_id or tb2_id. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Do i also have to add a for loop here: $tb1_id = mysqli_insert_id($db); ? If so, how to integrate it?

Comment: The for loop to insert multiple data into `tb2` should go **after** the call to `mysqli_insert_Id`. Otherwise - as you have seen - it will get the values from the inserts into `tb2`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, now it finally works!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.. try this..

```
BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO tb_1 (tb1_title, tb1_cat) VALUES ('$tb1_title', '$tb1_cat');
    INSERT INTO tb_2 (tb2_title, tb2_doc, <b>[? ? ?]</b>,id_tb1) VALUES ('$tb2_title', '$tb2_doc', <b>[? ? ?]</b>,LAST_INSERT_ID());
    COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqla = "INSERT INTO tableA (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2)";
mysqli_query($db,$sqla);
$id = mysqli_insert_id($db); //add it here.

$sqlb = "INSERT INTO tableB (col1,col2) VALUES (val1, val2, ...)";
//then you can pass the id into your second query
//...
```